# Google + API to get posts based on location

Tags: google-plus, google-data-api

Thanks for your time. 
I am writing an app with google plus data api. I need a help in that. I need to get all the public post from users in a specific location. Do you have any way to search for post from a location rather than a keyword.

Please reply.
Thanks,
Parvathy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, we do not currently offer this feature.  You can learn all about `activities.search` at https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/search.

However, we are constantly looking to improve our APIs.  Feel free to star this existing feature request in our Issue Tracker, and you will receive updates on this issue.  https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=33

Now that our Google+ Sign-In launch is complete, we will be using the Issue Tracker as our primary resource for developer bugs and feature requests.